# Object Manager doesn't retrieve some object?

Tags: custom-object

I can't retrieve my object ParametresMetier__c in the Object Manager,
Tho I can query it using Inspector as exemple,

I thought all objects where present in the Object Manager, wasn't it true ?

Thanks

Nb : I'm admin

Comment: When you say you can't retrieve, how exactly are you trying to access? Note that the list in Object Manager is lazy loaded, i.e., you will need to scroll further down to see all available objects if it's not available on the first screen. Or you can search for the object using its name in Quick Find.

Comment: Can you see if its an object and not a custom setting? Custom Settings look like normal Custom Objects can be used in SOQL but are Setup -> Custom Settings,

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Good point.

Comment: Yeap, this 'lazy loading' has already costs me, now I'm aware of it,

In fact I'm tired I think it may be some properties, not an object, I'm looking for.

It may be my bad..

Comment: Yes !! Thanks @PranayJaiswal you where right !
Always learning with Salesforce,
Thanks ;)

Comment: @PranayJaiswal You should add your comments as an answer which was the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom Setting even though ends with `__c` and queryable, its not present in Object Manager.

To access Custom Setting one has to visit `Setup -> Custom Setting`.

Comment: You can also see them in Developer Console under the Open Resources dialog.